# How to Add Test Project for MVC Project in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2013

I have an MVC 4.5.1 project in Visual Studio 2013. It is already well built out and working.
I need to add unit tests to it. How can I add a testing project?

It doesn't seem like the options available to do this for previous versions of Visual Studio are the same in 2013.

Additional info: I'll be using NUnit and Moq for testing.

Comment: did you ever google it? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410597%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just add a library project for tests and then install nunit and moq packages.